# Adjusting JS Live Search to show results regardless of word order

Tags: javascript, search, filter, livesearch

I created a simple javascript live search & disappear to filter names from a list, but now I'm running into trouble when someone searches for "John Smith" and can't find him because he's in the list as "John H. Smith". Is there anything I can add to the js code to have the search look for the input's contents regardless of word order or if there's a middle initial or middle name between the first name and last name?

Codepen for reference: https://codepen.io/naomimekeel/pen/rNzoeGQ

View the live page example: https://www.giveto.pitt.edu/s/1729/18/interior-giving.aspx?sid=1729&gid=2&pgid=5065

```
<div class="facstaffsearchbar">
    <input type="text"
           id="facstaff-search"
           name="facstaff-search"
           rel="facstaff-search"
           placeholder=" Search for a donor on this list . . ." />
        <div id="none">Sorry, no results found! Please check your spelling or try again.</div>

    <div rel="facstaff-data" id="facstaff-data">
        <div class="facstaff-data-item">+Terry Laughlin KGSB ’81 & Regina L. Aldisert</div>
<div class="facstaff-data-item">+Dr. W. Harry Archer, DEN ’27, A&S ’37 & +Mrs. Louise E. Archer, A&S ’27</div>
<div class="facstaff-data-item">+Lauren H. Ashe, A&S ’14</div>
</div>
```

```
let foundOne = false;
const none = document.getElementById('none');
const searchInput = document.querySelector('input[rel="facstaff-search"]');
const data = document.querySelectorAll(".facstaff-data-item");
show(false);
searchInput.addEventListener('input', function (event) {
    // reset state
    show(false)
    foundOne = false;
    const input = event.target
    if (input.value) {
        const toMatch = input.value.toLowerCase();
        for (let i = 0, len = data.length; i < len; i++) {
            const match = data[i].innerHTML.toLowerCase().includes(toMatch);
            data[i].style.display = match ? 'block' : 'none';
            if (match) foundOne = true;
        }
        if (!foundOne) show(true);
    } else 
        resetState()

});
function resetState() {
    for (let i = 0, len = data.length; i < len; i++)
        data[i].style.display = 'block';
    
}
function show(bool) {
    none.style.display = bool ? 'block' : 'none';
}
```

Comment: A quick solution would be to split the name and check if both of the array elements you got match to the name.  `const match = toMatch.split(" ").every(part => data[i].innerHTML.toLowerCase().includes(part));`

Comment: That sounds promising! Would this solution take over one of the other lines in the script or be an addition to it? I'm super new to javasript and tried inserting your code into my script in a couple different places but couldn't get it to work as expected.

Comment: This should replace your `const match = data[i].innerHTML.toLowerCase().includes(toMatch);`

Comment: @Babis.amas Thank you!! That works perfectly. I really appreciate the help.